# While in vi how can I pull in / insert / paste the contents of another file

Tags: vim, vi

- I am editing file 'A' in vi.
- I have another file 'B' whose contents I want to 'paste' into my current location.
- Other than actual mouse copy and pasting, is there a command that I can use that will pull in the content of another file to my current edit location.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620672/copy-and-paste-content-from-one-file-to-another-file-in-vi) is what you want?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Type the following

```
:r filename_to_paste
```

This will paste the contents of the file after the line on which the cursor is present.

---

If you need to copy/paste smaller range of lines/block of text from one file to other, you can also do the following assuming one file is opened in `vim` already

- Open 2<sup>nd</sup> file using `:sp` (split) or `:vsp`(vertical split)
- do a normal `yy` (yank) commands in the other file
- do `p` (paste) command back in the 1<sup>st</sup> file, as the register (place where yanked text is stored) is common to both the files.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> twice to switch between splited files.

Comment: Looks good.  Will accept soon.

Answer (score 1):

That `:r filename` is the shortest for whole files. If you want only one more small portions, I always go to the source file and use `"a57Y` `"b12Y` to copy specific lines to registers (registers `"a` and `"b` in these examples), which I can retrieve with `"ap` and `"bp` in the destination file.

Answer (score 0):

In insert mode, Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and then <kbd>=</kbd>.
Now, you are in command line mode and a 'equal to' sign is shown.

Type

```
      system('cat filename')
```

The content of another file 'filename' is pasted in next line of cursor.

Explanation:

`Ctrl+R` pastes the content of any register. `=` executes/evaluates the function/expression. Hence, you paste the output of the expression through `Ctrl` + `R` and `=`

`cat` is a Linux command which shows the content of a file.

Edit: this works in vim, not vi.